# how do I get the calendar object with AngularJS ui-calendar using the "controller as" syntax?

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui

I am using [ui-calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) from angular-ui. It's very nice and easy to use.

However, I am unable to get a hold of **calendar object** to call `fullCalendar()` and execute certain functions on the calendar.

The documentation only gives examples using the `$scope` approach, but I am using the `controller as vm` approach recommended by John Papa and others. I have tried using it this way:

```
<div data-ng-controller="races as vm">
    <div ui-calendar="vm.calendarConfig" calendar="vm.calendar"></div>
</div>
```

in the races controller I have the following:

```
vm = this;
vm.calendarConfig = { header: {...} };
vm.calendar = {};

// somewhere else in a separate click event
vm.calendar.fullCalendar('prev');    // ---> exception
```

That last line throws an exception `Object has no method 'fullCalendar'`.

Just wondering what I am missing and if anyone had an example of using `ui-calendar` with a `controller as vm` syntax.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DPo9meJHx19bREYFLhDh

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Mazzu, the code needed is up there. The actual code is a combination of ASP.NET MVC and some large bootstrap templates. Totaling 1000s of lines. It would probably confuse readers more than help. If this does not get any traction, I'll try to simplify the problem and put it up on plunker or something.

Comment: here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DPo9meJHx19bREYFLhDh

Comment: @Martinsos, do you have experience in using ui-calendar with angularJS? I know my object does not have a fullCalendar method. That's the point of the post: How do I pass the actual "calendar" object to my controller? from the documentation, I should be using the calendar="xxxx" option on the <div>. However, using the vm.calendar syntax does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [Josh Kurz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1510471/joshkurz) for your help. Here is what I ended up doing: I used a hybrid of the $scope and `controller as` approach.
Basically, I added a dependency on `$scope` to my controller. When I need access to the actual calendar control, I use `$scope.calendar.fullCalendar('...')`. The plunker has been updated, but here is core of it in the script file:

```
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$scope', races];
function races($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    ...
    function next() {
        $scope.calendar.fullCalendar('next');
    }
}
```

and in the html:

```
...
<div ui-calendar ng-model="vm.eventSources" calendar="calendar"></div>
...
```

Not as clean as I would like it, but it still seems clean enough for my purpose.

Comment: I tried that as well, but I wanted to solve the issue without changing your code. But good thing though... better to change the controllers than the lower level directives.

Comment: i added <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" calendar="myCalendar1" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div> in html but myCalendar1 is not accessible in my controller

Comment: @AnkitGupta you need to get it from the $scope, not from the controller. Also keep in mind that this is a few months old. I think fullCalendar release its 2.x version and others might have created a module or something...

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

To accomplish this with your exact syntax I had to hack the uiCalendar. 
I added one condition that checks for a controller-as attribute on the directive. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/6Jj0UHD7A8a1v8SRZrYP?p=preview

```
<div ui-calendar ng-model="vm.eventSources" controller-as="vm" calendar="calendar"></div>


if(attrs.controllerAs){
  scope.calendar = scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.controllerAs)[attrs.calendar] =  elm.html('');
} else {
  scope.calendar = scope.$parent[attrs.calendar] =  elm.html('');
}
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it works. Not tested either, so use at your own discretion...

I think this could be a valid PR for the calendar if more people find it useful, but this is the first request I have heard of this type.

Comment: thanks for the info. Don't worry about making those changes permanent unless you get more requests. I think I found a decent compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked after I used the controllerAs in the route and then add var vm = this.